Should we close it or leave it up?
Update: The question was closed, then re-opened by 5 community voters, then "locked", and it currently remains "locked".
Today I rushed to ask a question that by its nature will be stale by tomorrow. I was always planning on spiking it by tomorrow for that reason.  I'm happy that as I had hoped at least some people are having a small amount of fun with it.
Now there's a solid answer that goes above-and-beyond just answering it. So it cannot be deleted but I'd still like to close it.
I'm worried that future visitors will be frustrated with the question if they come across it without any other context or without reading the answer; I love that our forum is international and I'm not sure if the context translates well world-wide. Parts of the question are also US (or at least Western)-centric as well. Further there are a number of upvotes to the question but it's hard to tell whether the upvotes were born out of interest in the question itself, or more in the nature of the joke behind the question.
What does closing a question with at least one upvoted answer do? Is that a good option for the question of interest?

having decided to close it anyway, I think it might be a good idea to lock it instead. We could use the "historical reasons" locking (meaning a banner will appear saying it's off-topic but kept for "historical reasons"). The rationale being that it's good to keep it, but it's also not a post that we want other people to answer or interact with. To some degree, it's a kind of question that "expires". Locking it keeps it for future reference, but clearly marks it as being a special case, and prevents future interactions. Note that locking also freezes (but doesn't erase) votes and comments

also, you missed using "should it stay or should it go" as title.. so close

I’m ok with whatever the community decides. Locking also sounds good. A historical reason for keeping it locked- some yokel (me) attempted to convince bunch of folks into thinking that RSA is dead on April Fools… I strongly doubt it but if RSA is dead within a year it’ll be prophetic!

Yes, I agree. We should close that question.

what does closing a question with an upvoted answer do?

I am not sure. However, I think this question is bound to cause confusion/frustration/misguidance to other people in the future. Another option would be to just edit the title by adding [April's Fool joke] at the beginning or something.

@FDGod please see this: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/222/5

@Mark Closing won't affect answers in any way. It just means that no new answers can be added. (Only if votes are negative the question might be deleted eventually, which is not the case here). I'd agree that closing it with a clear close reason would be a good way to deal with it. Serious answers debunking such a claim should be underneath a serious question in that direction. One other option might be, of course, that you edit your question accordingly (with a reference to its history, potentially), so the answers would make sense even without being aware of the context in which it was asked
